# Script fails with spaces in directory names

Tags: shell

I have a really easy question, I have found a bunch of similar questions answered but none that solved this for me.

I have a shell script that goes through a directory and prints out the number of files and directories in a sub directory, followed by the directory name.

However it fails with directories with spaces, it attempts to use each word as a new argument. I have tried putting $dir in quotations but that doesn't help. Perhaps because its already in the echo quotations.

```
for dir in `find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d`
do
    echo -e "`ls -1 $dir | wc -l`\t$dir"
done
```

Thanks in advance for your help :)

Comment: Whatever happened to `find . -mindepth ... | while read dir; do ...; done` *sigh*

Comment: @robertklep Well -- that version isn't quite right; it mishandles some names with backslashes in them, names ending in IFS characters, and any name containing a newline. Also, any changes made to variables within the while loop are disregarded when it exits, on account of being on the right-hand-side of the pipeline.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy and the originally posted version (to which I'm responding) catches all those issues? ;)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy This depends on the shell, `ksh` executes the last command of a pipe in the current shell.

Comment: @robertklep No, but the point of responses here is to help people do things the right way.

Comment: @AdrianFrühwirth True for ksh and zsh, not true for ash, dash, bash (without the non-default `shopt -s lastpipe`), or bourne.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy indeed, and `for i in \`find ...\`` is not doing things the right way, which I was pointing out (in a comment, not an answer).

Answer (score 5):

*Warning*: Two of the three code samples below use bashisms. Please take care to use the correct one if you need POSIX sh rather than bash.

---

Don't do any of those things. If your real problem does involve using find, you can use it like so:

```
shopt -s nullglob
while IFS='' read -r -d '' dir; do
  files=( "$dir"/* )
  printf '%s\t%s\n' "${#files[@]}" "$dir"
done < <(find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -print0)
```

However, for iterating over only immediate subdirectories, you don't need find at all:

```
shopt -s nullglob
for dir in */; do
  files=( "$dir"/* )
  printf '%s\t%s\n' "${#files[@]}" "$dir"
done
```

If you're trying to do this in a way compatible with POSIX sh, you can try the following:

```
for dir in */; do
  [ "$dir" = "*/" ] && continue
  set -- "$dir"/*
  [ "$#" -eq 1 ] && [ "$1" = "$dir/*" ] && continue
  printf '%s\t%s\n' "$#" "$dir"
done
```

You shouldn't ever use `ls` in scripts: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

You shouldn't ever use `for` to read lines: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor

Use arrays and globs when counting files to do this safely, robustly, and without external commands: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/004

Always NUL-terminate file lists coming out of `find` -- otherwise, filenames containing newlines (yes, they're legal in UNIX!) can cause a single name to be read as multiple files, or (in some find versions and usages) your "filename" to not match the real file's name. http://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind

Comment: Awesome thanks :) As you can tell I am prety new to to this.
I wonder if you could explain a couple lines to me? -- IFS='' read -r -d '' dir -- files=( "$dir"/* ) -- done < <(find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -print0) -- And also, it says nullglob is invalid option name

Comment: @Chris If it says nullglob is invalid, your shell probably isn't bash (and other parts of this also won't work). See the "choose your shell" section of mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Practices

Comment: @Chris I added a POSIX-compliant version of the answer; that one should work for you.

Comment: Any answer referencing Greg's wiki deserves a *+1*.